# Sand clock script example or algorithm

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to release a mobile application (timer) as a sand clock in HTML5/javascript. Until I was able to do visual part with sprites, but it does not look too good.
Can anyone suggest a link to a similar clock example or algorithm implementation?

Comment: Don't post cyrillic text. And you're being downvoted since you're not showing any research effort.

Comment: did the answer you got solve your problem? if so you should "accept" it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems good1

http://geeksretreat.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/html5-canvas-an-egg-timer-hourglass-with-animated-falling-sand/

Comment: @Blackrid: If it does solve your problem, than mark it as answer.